# Can I say “noun is king”?

Tags: grammar

I’ve been researching if it is grammatically correct to Say  is king. For instance, we say “money is king”. “Cash is king”.

The very specific phrase I would like to write is “Remote work is king”. Which I believe means remote job is the best, better than office based jobs.

Comment: "Remote work is king" is grammatically correct.
It's less punchy than the examples you mention though, and without any context and coming out of the blue it might be a little hard to understand for someone less familiar than you are with the expression 'remote work'. If that bothers you you might consider giving it some context by saying, for example, "In the world of employment remote work is king."

Comment: Grammar aside, I don't think the statement "remote work is king" is true, unless perhaps you qualify it, e.g., "in the world of [some industry], remote work is king". The idiom "X is king" indicates that X trumps other options, which really isn't the case with working remotely, indeed in many industries working remotely isn't even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say something "*Is king*" means to say it is the best to the speaker.

I mean, The speaker thinks what they are talking about is the best.

It's all really opinion based. ***Is king*** is really a simile.

Comment: This doesn't add supporting evidence that 'X is king' where X is an abstract noun, is _always_ considered acceptable, which is what OP requests. The question is tagged 'grammar', not 'meaning'.